# Enable SSO with Spring OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, security

I'm trying to implement SSO using Spring OAuth lib for learning purpose.
The AuthenticationServer looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory() //
                .withClient("acme") //
                .secret("acmesecret") //
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password") //
                .scopes("openid");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
   }
}
```

WebSecurity like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthorizeUrlsSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and() //
                .logout().and() //
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

and RestController:

```
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/user/me")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

The web application is kept minimal:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  security:
    basic:
      enabled: false
    oauth2:
      client:
        clientId: acme
        clientSecret: acmesecret
        accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9999/auth/oauth/token
        userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9999/auth/oauth/authorize
      resource:
        userInfoUri: http://localhost:9999/auth/user/me
```

when I enter the URL localhost:8080 I should be redirect to the login (generated by spring?), but I get a 401 error.

```
2018-09-29 12:42:28.257 DEBUG 7677 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
```

What am I missing?
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if I can follow you, should I add a PasswordEncoder?

Comment: I am not saying to follow by accepted answer in previous comment, but there is also second answer

Comment: Most of the time CORS (status code 401) encounter because CORS security chain is not configured.

Comment: Following this tutorial https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v I should be able to run the AuthServer and enter the URL in the browser to get redirect, but I still get 401 error...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set web security configuration in the web application.

The reason why you get 401 is even the login url is not allowed to be connected by Spring Security.

So basically you need to add a java config like the following

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Following the javadoc of EnableOAuthSso "If the user only has EnableOAuth2Sso but not on a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter then one is added with all paths secured." I have already tried it your solution, but it doesn't work either.